# omit dialect prefix from thymeleaf processor

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, processor, dialect

Is there any way to omit the dialect prefix from a thymeleaf processor? Let's say I have defined a processor like this:

```
<dialect:processor> ... </dialect:processor>
```

is there some way to modify the dialect class to be able to use the tag this way:

```
<processor> ... </processor>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to reduce the amount of text?

Comment: Not only this, but I want "override" some of the html tags to make them get data from model and display in the view, without have to write a lot of code.